# How to redefine macro in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using jinja2 through sphinx. In my base template (*layout.html* I have some some macro

```
{%- macro post_meta(metadata) -%}
    <div class="postmeta">
        {{ author(metadata.author) }}
    </div>
{%- endmacro -%}
```

I'm extending this template in *theme2* with `{%- extends "theme1/layout.html" -%}`

How can I redefine `post_meta` in *theme2*? Simple putting new definition of `post_meta` in *theme2* doesn't work.

By the way how can I use python buildin function like:

```
{{ type(metadata) }}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q1: You have to create a block to override the block with the macro in your base template. This is the code for the child. With use_child = False : the macro in the base template will be used

```
{% block pm_mac %}
    {% if use_child %}
        {%- macro post_meta(metadata) -%}
               .....
        {%- endmacro -%}
    {% else %}        
        {{ super() }}
    {% endif %} 
{% endblock %}
```

Q2: You have to register a global Python function to use type :

```
def py_to_upper(a):
    return a.upper()

env.globals['to_upper'] = py_to_upper # register the global python function


and in the Jinja template :

{{ to_upper("lowercase") }}
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution for Q1 looks like dirty workaround, but it seems that there is no clean solution.